# The session works fine in backend, but it doesn't work when I send a request with frontend

Tags: angular, laravel, api, session, captcha

The session works fine in backend, but it doesn't work when I send a request with frontend

in controller:

```
public function captcha(){
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['captcha_image'])) {
        File::delete($_SESSION['captcha_image']);
        $temp = new Captcha();
        $temp->captcha();
        return response()->json(['url_image' => $_SESSION['captcha_image'],
                                'captcha' => $_SESSION['captcha']], Response::HTTP_OK);

    } else {
        $temp = new Captcha();
        $temp->captcha();
        return response()->json(['url_image' => $_SESSION['captcha_image'],
                                'captcha' => $_SESSION['captcha']], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

create session :

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $word;
$_SESSION['captcha_image'] = "image".$time.".png";
```

Comment: No need to write `session_start();`

Comment: You can use laravel default Session. Where is your front end?

Comment: Mr STA, If I don't write session_start, it gives an error

Comment: Mr A.A Noman Sessions in Laravel are only used for user and for login, I want to use session for other work. In frontend I use angular5  and a simple method GET

Answer (score 0):

You may use Laravel session:

1. via a `Request` instance:

   ```php
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   public function captcha(Request $request)
   {
       if ($request->session()->has('captcha_image')) {
           File::delete($request->session()->get('captcha_image'));
       }

       $temp = new Captcha();
       $temp->captcha();

       return response()->json([
           'url_image' => $request->session()->get('captcha_image'),
           'captcha' => $request->session()->get('captcha'),
       ], Response::HTTP_OK);
   }
   ```
2. via the global `session` helper method:

   ```php
   public function captcha()
   {
       if (session('captcha_image')) {
           File::delete(session('captcha_image'));
       }

       $temp = new Captcha();
       $temp->captcha();

       return response()->json([
           'url_image' => session('captcha_image'),
           'captcha' => session('captcha'),
       ], Response::HTTP_OK);
   }
   ```

To store a data in the session:

```php
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/session) for more info.

Comment: The session in Laravel is for users only, while I do not have access to the user before logging in. So I can not use seasion laravel here

Comment: @MohammadReza What you mean that the session is for users only? every client (guest or authenticated) has a session, just try the above code.

Comment: .Do you think I can create a session for each user before logging in? I can not, because I do not have user information before logging in.